# Error:Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void add(List<Contact>) from the type List<List<GetContact.methodOutputs>>

Tags: apex, class, list, fields, invocable-method

I am trying to pass a firstname and lastname to an invocable method and get a list back of contacts filterd on firstname and lastname but get the error before saving my class:

> ```
> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void add(List<Contact>) from the type List<List<GetContact.methodOutputs>>
> ```

On line: `theResults.add(cntList);`

**My class**

```
public class GetContact {
    @InvocableMethod (label = 'Get Contact' description = 'Get a Contact.')
    public static List<List<methodOutputs>> getContactIds (List<methodInputs> request) {
        List<Contact> cntList = [SELECT id, FirstName, LastName from Contact WHERE FirstName = :request[0].FirstName and LastName = :request[0].LastName]; 
        List<List<methodOutputs>> theResults = new List<List<methodOutputs>>();
        theResults.add(cntList);    
        return theResults;        
    }  

    public class methodInputs{
        @InvocableVariable
        public String FirstName;
        @InvocableVariable
        public String LastName;
    }
    public class methodOutputs{
        @InvocableVariable
        public List<List<Contact>> cntList ;
    } 
}
```

What am I missing? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you exactly what's going on here. You have mismatched types, and you are not allowed to add a `List<Contact>` to a `List<List<GetContact..MethodOutputs>>`. That said, with your current setup you do not have to do any `add` operations, as your `List<List>` is just an attribute on the output.

**Incorrect**

```
List<List<methodOutputs>> theResults = new List<List<methodOutputs>>();
theResults.add(cntList);
return theResults;
```

**Correct**

```
List<List<methodOutputs>> theResults = new List<List<methodOutputs>>();
theResults.cntList = cntList;
return theResults;
```